# Is chaos theory really a theory? Why not just call it non-linear dynamics?

Tags: soft-question, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

This may just be semantics, but it's always confused me. What is the thesis of Chaos Theory? I have read an entire book about it, and as far as I can tell, its just a bunch of analytical techniques, but there is no underlying object "chaos" that is being characterized, its just a bunch of sophisticated tools for parsing nonlinear dynamical systems.

As a counterexample, Matrix Theory is about the behavior of vector spaces and operations on them, the theory of linear ODEs leads to elegant proofs of some properties. But what are some proofs/theorems about "chaos" -- the closest thing I can find is that phase-space trajectories have a positive Lyapunov exponent...there must be more than that!

Comment: In grant applications, a nice title helps.

Comment: @AndréNicolas lol...love it ;-)

Comment: Try answering the question, "What is a theory?"  If you can do that, then you can try and apply the definintion of "theory" to our knowledge of chaotic systems.  Looking at "theory" etymologically, we find (and I hope memory serves me well here) it is based on ancient Greek words *theoria* or *theoros*,  contemplate, speculate, observe, view.  From such a point of reference, a theory is simply a collection of observations or contemplations of a subject.  So we shouldn't expect too much of theories *per se*; a theory can be conceptually well organized, or indeed "chaotic".  *Caveat Emptor!*

Comment: @RobertLewis point well taken...the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on Chaos goes into this a bit. However, the hype surrounding Chaos led me to believe it was introducing a new "paradigm" or new object, somewhat like the Lorentz-transformation of the space-time vector is a new idea in Special relativity.

Comment: "There must be more to it than that" - for example, the Ornstein isomorphism theorem is a classical example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein_isomorphism_theorem

Comment: @Carl Mummert:  I'm sure there is *much* more to it that, I was merely trying to caution against expecting too much from a subject simply because it bears the moniker "theory".  By the way, thanks for the reference to Ornstein, I'll have to check out his papers in my copious spare time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nonlinear dynamical systems can be quite roughly divided in two huge realms: the realm of order (continuous time two dimensional systems) and the realm of chaos (dimension three and above for continuous time systems).

The former is mostly about 16'th Hilbert problem about the number of limit cycles on the plane and still is a huge area of research. The other one is about most "hyperbolicity" and how to classify the flows in higher dimensions.  So, despite the cynical comment of @ AndreNicolas, there is an excellent reason to talk about Chaos theory.

Comment: thanks for the example about the logistic map. I thought that would not be possible!

Comment: @julianfernandez You are very welcome. It just shows that very often explicitly written formulas of no use.

Comment: @Artem thanks for the response. So, what new insights into the nature of chaos has chaos theory provided? The Orstein isomorphism is definitely interesting, but it appears to be about something more general than chaotic systems (for example, it includes stochastic processes, whereas chaos appears to be about deterministic systems).

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Except for "thank you" I did not get what your question is. In particular, I have no idea what the Orstein isomorphism is. To answer your own question you first should define what chaos is. But this is that main topic of the whole chaos theory.

Comment: @Artem apologies for any confusion I was referring to something in the comments that appeared to be relevant. Here's a different take: what is the object of study in Chaos theory and what have we learned about this object that we didn't know before? E.g. linear algebra studies vector spaces and rotations/scaling transformations.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 We, humans, have an intuitive understanding of the chaos. Look at some water flows in mountings. The mathematical theory tries to formalize, and hence, study these phenomena. It a first approximation it tries to rigorously say what "chaos" is.

Comment: @Artem OK...so what does this first approximation look like. For example, Newtons Equations are a "first approximation" to General Relativity, and they looks like "F=ma", so a constant force produces a constant acceleration (true to a good approximation). What does this formalized chaos look like? Just like I have an intuitive idea of what "pressure" is, I know what chaos looks like...but thermodynamics and statistical mechanics conceptualize this common intuition in different ways.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 You mentioned that you read an entire book. If you do not have an idea now what this first approximations is, maybe you should get another book.

Comment: @Artem This could have been your fist post then...what my book said is that chaotic systems are "sensitive" (i.e., have a positive lyapunov exponent), and here are a bunch of ways to look a these systems. That is fine, but it seems like these are just tools. It didn't leave me with a better understanding of the properties of chaos. I don't think this dialog will get much further. It may be that the "theory" is really a methodological theory, as opposed to an object-oriented theory like linear algebra.

Comment: Chaos theory is not "the theory of chaos". It is the theory of chaotic dynamical systems. We do indeed know more about these systems, e.g. using quantitative tools such as Lyapunov exponents and entropy. And we have very surprising results such as Ornstein's theorem, which I linked to before, and many more results since then ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein_isomorphism_theorem ). It seems you simply chose a poor book. Perhaps the book by Katok and Hasselblatt would be better.  @Eupraxis1981

Comment: @CarlMummert thanks for the clarification. Is there a decent online discussion of such results? My text appears to be excessively focused on the tools but not what was discovered using those tools. That is the part that was confusing me. Its like saying that "chemistry" is only about lab technique...which, of course, is only a means to an end. Can you provide a couple links to genuine Chaos Theory findings about the properties/nature of chaotic dynamical systems? Thanks :-)

Comment: One possible resource is "Hyperbolicity and recurrence in dynamical systems: a survey of recent results" by Luis Barreira, online at  http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~barreira/preprints/barreira_resenhas.pdf .  Someone more versed than I am in the theory might be able to recommend other resources.